# SSRS parameter returns a data type that is not valid

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I got the Tumbleweed badge for this question....  :)

## I've moved on a little from the original question but still looking at using internal/hidden parameters, this time passing to another report which runs a stored procedure (which sends an email).

The main report (report A) has a parameter called StudentCourses (originally called ReportParameter1) which I have tried both as Hidden or Internal, and currently has ticked Allow blank value and Allow multiple values.
*(Its default value is a field from the result of a query, which shows the courses a student is enrolled on).*

Action for my textbox no longer goes to URL (to open PHP form) but now uses Go to report to call report B. Under action options I've added two parameters; StudNetworkID and StudCourses. The number of courses can vary from 2 to 5.

The new report (report B) has two parameters also called StudNetworkID and StudCourses; both are Hidden and StudCourses has ticked Allow blank value. [All parameters are text, btw].

> If Report A StudCourses is set to =Parameters!StudentCourses.Value(0) then the first course is shown on Report B. So far so good.
>
> If Report B StudCourses is set to Allow multiple values, then Report B shows #Error and the Warning description given is "[rsInvalidExpressionDataType] The Value expression used in textrun ‘Textbox3.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ returned a data type that is not valid."
>
> If Report B StudCourses is set to NOT Allow multiple values and Report A StudCourses value is set to [@StudentCourses] then Report B shows the text "[@StudentCourses]".
>
> If Report B StudCourses is set to Allow multiple values again, then I get the same invalid data type error as before.

Having turned off Allow multiple values on Report B to avoid the #Error issue...

> Setting Report A StudCourses to =Parameters!StudentCourses.Value(0) & Parameters!StudentCourses.Value(1) then Report B shows course 1 and course 2 on one line. OK so far.
>
> However, setting Report A StudCourses to =Parameters!StudentCourses.Value(0) & Parameters!StudentCourses.Value(1) & Parameters!StudentCourses.Value(2) gives me a runtime error that the Index was outside the bounds of the array (because there are currently only two courses). On clicking the textbox, Report B just says "The 'StudCourses' parameter is missing a value".

OK...

> I turned off Allow multiple values on Report A StudentCourses parameter (the one holding the result from the query) and for the Go to report parameter StudCourses I added the other values, so eventually had value(0) to value(4), the result was interesting. For each parameter value used it gave me a letter from the first course on Report B. Hence when I included up to value(4) it gave me the first five letters of course one!

Yep, ok, this is because it is no longer reading multiple values and so specifying a number just returns the letter from that position.

SO...

*How do I allow for up to 5 courses to be passed over???*

## What follows below is the original question

I have a small report designed in Visual Studio that displays courses that a student is enrolled on. The number of courses can vary from 2 to 5, depending on the student.

Also on the report is a text box, which when clicked will action a url to open a PHP form.

I have worked out how to pass the user id to this PHP form but, if possible, I would also like to pass the course titles.

If I use internal report parameters* I can add these to the url, like this:

```
="http://myurl/webform.php?param=" & Mid(User!UserID,InStrRev(User!UserID,"\")+1) 
& Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value(0)
& Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value(1)
& Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value(2)
& Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value(3)
& Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value(4)
```

but unfortunately I get the runtime error "The Hyperlink expression for the text box 'Textbox7' contains an error: Index was outside the bounds of the array."

If I just put the first two report parameters it works fine.

I tried using parameter count, e.g. iif(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Count > 2, Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value(2), " "), but I still get the same error.

Please can someone show me how to get around this runtime error, or suggest another way to do this?

Thanks

PS * Report Parameters set up as Text, Allow blank value, Allow multiple values, Internal, Available Values = None, Default Values = Get values from a query; Value field = course title.

Comment: What does your URL output look like? Is there some delimiter like "," ? Only reason I ask is because it looks like you are concatenating a bunch of parameters together with no separator, I'm not sure how a page would know how to separate the parameters later.

Comment: Hi, yes you're quite right. I was going to look at tidying that up later, once I'd got past the out of bounds error.

Comment: Your expression is referencing indexes of values that may or may not exist (out of bounds error), you could try using a single parameter and build some multi dimensional string object that you break apart in report code (i.e. "Value1=Value,Value2=Value,Value3=Value" ). While this is not ideal, it would be easier to work with.

Comment: That is precisely where I need the help...I tried doing it using parameter count (mentioned in my original post) but that didn't work.                   Note that I have moved on from "Go to Url" to "Go to Report" but have the same out of bounds issue when trying to specify the parameters to move to the report.

Comment: I tried "[@StudentCourses]" which I had seen in another question but that didn't work.